# How to programatically change a bootstrap dropdown to an specific state?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

In the documentation I see I can programmatically toggle a dropdown by doing:

```
$().dropdown('toggle')
```

That works fine, but what if I want to dropdown to be shown or not shown?  Is there a way to do something like this?

```
$().dropdown('show')
$().dropdown('hide')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [docs](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#dropdowns) the only method there is for bootstrap dropdowns is `toggle`. However you can use the `aria-expanded` attribute to see if the dropdown is expanded or not. For example, if you wanted to "hide" all of the dropdowns you would do something like this:

```
$(".dropdownClass").each(function(){
   if($(this).attr("aria-expanded") == true) //depending on your jQuery version you may want to use .prop() instead of .attr()
      $(this).dropdown('toggle');
});
```

Comment: I ended up doing it similar to this.  It seems kind of hacky but it works.

Answer (score 0):

I'm slightly confused by your question. Calling `$().dropdown('toggle')` will reverse the state of the dropdown. For instance, it will show the dropdown if the dropdown is hidden; or hide the dropdown if it's open.

There are no methods aside from `toggle` that can be called for the dropdown.

Edit: you can register [listeners](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#dropdowns) for some of the other instance events (like `show.bs.dropdown` for instance, so you can use code to check if the dropdown is being shown, but cannot invoke it directly aside from using `toggle`, as mentioned)

Comment: I want to make it a known state instead of toggling the state.  For example I'm dynamically filling the options and if there are options it should be displayed as open, if there are no options it should be displayed as closed.

Comment: @Sgraffite Then all you'll need to do is invoke the `toggle` method after you've populated the menu. Perhaps adding some more source code to the question will help generate more targeted answers?

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't seem possible: Dropdown plugin seems to only have two public methods (`toggle` and `keydown`). And `toggle` does not accept any arguments for customization - only event.

Take a look at the source code yourself: https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.js